# how to use or how to connect the phpmailers file in slim framework Index.php file

Tags: php, slim

I am using slim framework for a webapp, I want to send an email.
Some have used below code in `index.php` in slim framework. But I don't know how to use these lines without any `autoload.php` file or without vendor folder in downloaded folder from PHPMailer.

```
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer; 
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

So please anyone can help me for the email sending through slim framework with `index.php` file using and send email code?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you run `composer install`?

Comment: Thank you for your response @Nima.   no composer install yet.Actually I am new or I am learner slim.

Comment: How did you add PHPMailer library to your project? Did you include any file in index.php to use PHPMailer class?

Comment: Thank you for your response `Nima`. I have not any idea for the include in slim framework .

Comment: can you please give me idea?

Comment: This not something related to Slim framework. How familiar are you with writing programs using PHP?

Comment: Thank you @Nima, normally we including files in same coding file like if we are using index.php file for send email ,we added on index.php file. and after that we using class or object. but in slim I have another index.php file for all include file like this

`require_once 'dbHandler.php';
require_once 'passwordHash.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';

\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();


require_once 'authentication.php';
require_once 'profile.php';
require_once 'employeeList.php'`

Comment: and another file that have us like 
`$app->get('/employee', function() {
 $db = new DbHandler();`

Comment: but if I include here 

`use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'vendor/autoload.php';`

and use the object created PHPMailer than show the error - PHPMailer not defined.

Comment: `vendor/autoload.php` is **the one file** that composer creates for you, that handles inclusion of all other required files (like what you're trying to do with the _other_ index.php file, I guess), and since you don't use composer (i.e. you did not run composer install) composer did not create that for you, so that is not the one file you need to include in your index.php. Please read [Installation & loading](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer#installation--loading) section of PHPMailer readme file for more details.

Comment: **Thank you @Nima** for your response and Sorry for late response or late back here. 

Your answer was really helpful, I have installed successfully, but now I have found the issue in sending email. Found the error of smtp connection.

Comment: **Error** ` 2018-09-17 14:03:35 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP 70-v6sm21284967pfz.27 - gsmtp<br>
2018-09-17 14:03:35 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: EHLO localhost<br>
2018-09-17 14:03:36 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [2409:4042:218d:504a:dc9b:b057:d060:c5b2]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-
ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8<br>
2018-09-17 14:03:36 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: STARTTLS<br>
2018-09-17 14:03:36 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS<br>
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.<br>_2018-09-17 14:03:37`

Comment: continue `2018-09-17 14:03:37 CLIENT -&gt; SERVER: QUIT<br>
2018-09-17 14:03:37 SERVER -&gt; CLIENT: <br>
2018-09-17 14:03:37 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: <br>
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.<br>
{"status":"error","message":"Ummmm Email could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host."}`

Comment: I'm glad you could successfully install the library. But please avoid asking a new questions in the comments, as this makes the question less likely to be seen by others, also, it will prevent proper formatting.

Comment: I strongly suggest that you work your way through the tutorial here: https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/tutorial/first-app.html

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
<?php

/** @see https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer */

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
require 'path/to/PHPMailer/src/SMTP.php';
```